# Retrieve Yelp & Foursquare urls of a Facebook place with FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to retrieve the Yelp & Foursquare URLs of a Facebook place with FQL (or Graph API). I looked at all fields of the Page and Place tables but I could not find this information in any fields.

Is there a way to get these URLs?

Here is an example of what I mean: https://www.facebook.com/BarDvars/info